# RestTemplate calling post with HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> internal data converted to base64

Tags: spring, base64, resttemplate

We have a spring microservice that calls other (also spring) microservice

**Client Service:**

Using restTemplate to call a service with POST action

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("somekey", someObject);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity  = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
```

...

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity, String.class);
```

The object that is passed "someObject" has some members that their value is in Russian

**Server Service:**

```
public ResponseEntity<Item> someName(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers,                                        
                                     @RequestParam("someObject") String data)
```

The data arrives fine to the server service, But , the **Russian** text is converted to the Base64 representation of that same text. So the data is not valid any more. English text looks fine

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , Found this
Had to upgrade spring version

from:

```
<version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
```

to:

```
<version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
```

Then tried to understand why this upgrade helped, figured out that we had this configuration set

```
spring.http.encoding.force-request=false
```

and when changed to

```
spring.http.encoding.force-request=true
```

Things started to work again without the need to upgrade at all

So why the upgrade helped?

The configuration:

```
spring.http.encoding.force-request
```

was deprecated in version 2.3.0 and was replaced with

```
 server.servlet.encoding.force-request
```

So because after upgrade it was "set" to default, then it worked